# Como criar Spinner dinâmico em Java

Tags: java, android

Olá, eu tenho uma dúvida sobre como criar três spinners dinâmicos interdependentes, ou seja, criar um primeiro spinner denominado "Módulo", a partir do valor selecionado o spinner "Sub módulo" exibir apenas os itens referentes a ele e a partir do valor do "Sub módulo" exibir os itens do spinner "Função" referentes ao sub módulo selecionado. Seria a mesma problemática de selecionar o item de um Spinner chamado "Estado" e o Spinner "Cidade" exibir apenas as cidades do estado selecionado.
 A estrutura das três tabelas no banco de dados é a seguinte:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ANDROID_MODULO(
    ID_MODULO INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    NMODULO VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE ANDROID_SUBMODULO(
    ID_SUBMODULO INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    ID_MODULO INT NOT NULL 
       REFERENCES ANDROID_MODULO 
       ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    NSUBMODULO VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE ANDROID_FUNCOES(
    ID_FUNCAO INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    ID_MODULO INT NOT NULL 
        REFERENCES ANDROID_MODULO(ID_MODULO) 
        ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    ID_SUBMODULO INT NOT NULL 
        REFERENCES ANDROID_SUBMODULO (ID_SUBMODULO) 
        ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    NFUNCAO  VARCHAR(60)
);
```

Eu estou conseguindo trazer o valor do módulo e gravar o id dele na tabela de Atendimentos, mas na exibição dos sub módulos e funções não estou conseguindo carregar os dados corretamente, desde já agradeço.

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesta pergunta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564891/android-dynamic-spinner